# Removing Adventurers

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Having just lost about a week of progress towards the Saoshyant achievement in my Crusader Kings 2 Ironman game, I am somewhat vexed.

Since adventurers are unbalanced, unrealistic and not remotely fun, I'd like to play without them. Unfortunately, I can't simply disable The Old Gods DLC as that would also disable Zoroastrians and the 867 start.

Is there a way to balance or remove adventurers while still being able to access Old Gods content and without disabling achievements?

Comment: No. Extra words for character limit.

Comment: The best advice is to just murder them before they arrive and take  the Dishonorable penalty on the chin.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees Which is what I normally do, only it doesn't work when they're too far away or part of a revolt war (temporary title). Incidentally, the revolt war failed and the adventurer's father was imprisoned because his son didn't lend him the 30000 strong maintenance-free attrition-proof unsullied doomstack he found in a two county realm.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable adventurers, but the easiest solution is to kill/assassinate the ringleaders as soon as possible.

Comment: That used to work wonders before the 2.2 patch. Now you have to run a plot... And if you fail you just get a huge enemy stack that is bigger than the world's largest empire's combined forces.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the accessible CK2 code, i.e. events etc, which I don't know right now, it *might* be possible to alter or remove adventurers. (Could possibly also be hardcoded, in which case you're out of luck.)

However, this will change the game's checksum and thus disable achievements for you. So, to answer your question: No, that's not possible.